# Placing a hook after each character insertion

Tags: hooks, insert-char

I'd like to define a minor mode in which, when I write something, point is not moved and the characters are instead inserted after point. I thought that would be easy: just add a hook after `insert-char` calling `backward-char`, so I wrote

```
(add-hook #'backward-char #'insert-char)
```

and nothing happened. I'm assuming this is because typing a character normally calls `insert-char` interactively. Then I noticed that even if it would have worked, the hook would probably call `backward-char` before `insert-char`, right? So, how do I do this: add a hook calling `backward-char` after a character is typed each time?

Comment: `backward-char` is not a hook (i.e. a variable that holds a list of functions and gets run at a specific point of a function). Most hooks are called `something-hook`, so one way to find out about them is to do `C-h v -hook TAB` to get the completions, The completion buffer will be big (there are lots of hooks that match this name - and some that don't so it is not completely reliable), but you can switch to the window with a couple of `C-x o` keys and then move around doing `C-h v` on anything that looks promising. It's not fast but it's faster than trying to assign to a random name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting characters into the buffer is normally done via
`self-insert-command`, which has a hook called `post-self-insert-hook`
that you can use:

```
(defun backward-char-after-insert ()
    (backward-char))
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 'backward-char-after-insert 100 t)
```

Here I deliberately set the local value of the hook, since I'm
assuming you don't want this behaviour everywhere :-)

Of course there are commands that insert text into the buffer without
passing through `self-insert-command`, so this might not get you 100%
of what you want.